# What does this line of code means?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am learning Zend Framework 2  and come across this line of code .

```
$serviceManager -> get('ModuleManager') -> loadModules();
```

What does this line of code mean?

Comment: This line of code basically means that you need to tear it apart and look each part up in the manual.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about being too lazy to look things up in the manual.

Comment: Well, i am reading the manual. But still i do not know what its means by serviceManager?

Comment: `serviceManager` is the name of a variable. It can mean *anything*, see http://php.net/variables - the concrete meaning depends on the type of the object that has been assigned to that variable. That type *is* documented in the ZF2 manual, however you first need to find out. An easy way is to place a breakpoint on that line, execute the code in the debugger and then inspect the type when the breakpoint is hit. (as you're using a big framework, I highly recommend to install http://xdebug.org/)

Comment: Please don't be too hard,..  I'm just a beginner.  Some concepts is really complex to understand, but i know i will get better sooner or later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea, but it seems quite straight-forward.

1. `$serviceManager` is probably a... manager of services.
2. `get('ModuleManager')` is probably a method that retrieves a... module manager.
3. `loadModules()` is probably a method that... loads the modules the previous manager manages.

Without knowing more about what you are doing, and where that code comes from, that is all we can say about this.

Go to the Zend website and [read the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/namespaces/Zend.html).

Comment: by services , its means for example a function that getName(), checkName()..  Thanks